# Cannot open Pycharm (Process 5,540 is still running)

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, pycharm, ide

When I am trying to open Pycharm on Ubuntu (22.04) I am getting the following error from time to time (around 50% of cases):
 `Cannot connect to already running IDE instance. Exception: Process 5,540 is still running`
Killing process: `sudo kill -9 5540` helps, but it is quite annoying and it would be nice to have clarity why this problem occurs.
Also on other machines and operating systems it does not seem to be the case.

Comment: This is a known issue with explanation: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-330531/Improve-Cannot-connect-to-already-running-IDE-instance-Exception-Process-processid-is-still-running-detection next time please [try this](https://giybf.com/)

Answer (score 1):

You need to delete the `.lock` file in the [configuration directory](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/directories-used-by-the-ide-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs.html#qacj9a_64):

```
${HOME}/.config/JetBrains/<product><version>/.lock
```

e.g.:

```
rm ~/.config/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2023.3/.lock
```